# GUI for managing automounting of fileshares?

Tags: sharing, macos, smb

I have a bunch of MP3 files on an SMB share. They play great if I use Finder's Connect to Server to mount the disk first, iTunes thinks they have names like /Volumes/musicshare/foo.mp3. But if I reboot and launch iTunes first the files are as if they don't exist until I manually remount the volume in Finder.

How do I arrange for my network share to automatically mount after a reboot? Searching for answers turns up a lot of information about hand-editing autofs configuration files. I'm new to MacOS but an old Unix hand and am OK editing files in /etc. But it feels like the wrong way; does MacOS have a user friendly way of automounting network shares?

Answer (score 2):

Mount the share that you want and then open "System Preferences - Users and groups - Login items"

Click the + symbol to add a new login item and then select the network share from the window that opens. The volume should open on every login.

Check the box next to it to hide the item. This should keep the Finder window from appearing.

Comment: Thanks, this works! Any way to prevent Finder from opening the window on login? I just wanted it mounted, don't need to see the folder.

Comment: Actually, after a few weeks this doesn't really work so well. On my iMac the network interface comes up slowly, and Finder hangs the whole boot process with a modal dialog because it can't mount the filesystem. And sometimes I lose the mount, I think after a long sleep.

Comment: After 2 more months I'm disabling the SMB share as a Login item. It blocks the system boot if it can't mount the server for whatever reason. I think I need to do something via autofs instead, there may be no GUI for setting that up.