# Finder drops connection to server / network attached storage

Tags: macbook-pro, finder, network, mojave, storage

I am trying to transfer data that takes days to complete and would like to have a permanent connection to my Network Attached Storage device. I can open finder, then go--> connect to server in order to connect to my network attached storage. However, if I return to my computer and there is a login screen, the connection has been dropped. I would like for the data transfer to continue even while I am logged out, and for the disk to be remounted even if the network connection is temporarily dropped.

I have enabled the connection as a login item as described in https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/20667/1942, but it still doesn't automatically mount the device. An answer to another question, https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/210960/1942, suggests writing an AppleScript to automate this, referencing a blog post from 2008 (>10y ago).

What are my options for automating the mounting in 2019?

I have a MacBook Pro + macOS Mojave 10.14.3

[image: output from smbutil statshares -a]

Comment: What is the protocol used to connect to the NAS? AFP, SMB? What is the NAS make?

Comment: @Gummibando using smb to connect to NAS; the make is [Buffalo TS1200D](https://www.buffalo-technology.com/productpage/terastation-1200ds/).

Comment: How are you connecting?  WiFi?  Ethernet?  What speed?

Comment: I am transferring via local Ethernet at about 10MB/s

Comment: @DavidLeBauer Sorry, even more questions.
1. The speed is really slow, what is the Ethernet link speed to the NAS (100 Mbit/s, 1 Gbit/s)?.
2. With the mounted share selected in the Finder, what does the Finder Info dialog (CMD-I) say under "Format"?
3. With the share munted, can you post the output of the Terminal/commandline command "smbutil statshares -a" (maybe add a screenshot to your original post)?
4. Can SSH be enabled on the Buffalo NAS to access the core system with admin privileges?
5. Do you know what the Samba (the SMB server software on the NAS) version is?

Comment: @Gummibando 1) my link speed is 54 Mbit/s 2) the info doesn't tell me anything about the format, but the disk is formatted as xfs 3) screenshot posted to OP 4) no, ssh isn't an option 5) the NAS interface says it is using the SMB2 protocol.

Comment: @Gummibando today I am getting ~20 MB/s from laptop to nas and ~35MB/s from  nas --> laptop (using `rsync --progress`)

Comment: Why is the link speed 54 MBits? This sounds like WiFi to me. Ethernet should be 100 MBit (Fast Ethernet) or 1 Gbit/s (Gigabit Ethernet), these are the Ethernet speeds the NAS supports, according to the specs. Even 20 MB/s transfer rate exceeds the link speed of 54 Mbits/s. Can you please recheck the Ethernet speed? I’m not familiar with the admin interface of Buffalo NASes, but is there somewhere an option to enable SMB Durable Handles? (This enables transparent reconnect for file operations.) Can you somehow see the logs of the SMB Server via the admin UI?

Comment: Does the Finder Info Format say “SMB” or “SMB (OSX)?

Comment: @Gummibando it says 'SMB (Unknown)'

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue of keeping the disk mounted by using the `caffeinate` command. Caffeinate keeps the system from sleeping as described in the [man page](https://ss64.com/osx/caffeinate.html).

Comment: Probably the simplest solution. The TeraStation setup seems very limited, which makes mitigating the issue at the SMB level more ore less impossible. (Just for comparison, at home I use a Synology NAS, which after a few lines of command line configuration, supports persistent connections, transparent reconnects, macOS meta data and transfer speeds north of 100 MB/s). If you don't want to fiddle around with the "caffeinate" command on the commandline, there is a nice free menu bar utility available for one-click-keep-awake functionality. https://github.com/newmarcel/KeepingYouAwake